# Laravel empty route parameter

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have multiple routes that will directed to the same controller and method. I want the second route will have empty customParams, but the first one will use the custom params. What should I do? Thanks

```
Route::get('{customParams?}/{slug}/{registrationCode}/detail', [SubmissionController::class, 'submissionDetail'])->name('submission.detail');

public function submissionDetail($customParams = '', $slug, $registrationCode)
{
    //
}
```

The first route was running perfectly

```
 <a href="{{ route('submission.detail', ['customParams' => 'riwayat-pengajuan', 'slug' => $cs->service->slug, 'registrationCode' => $cs->registration_code]) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Detail</a>
```

The second route did not work and produced a 404 page

```
 <a href="{{ route('submission.detail', ['slug' => $cd->service->slug, 'registrationCode' => $cd->registration_code]) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Detail</a>
```

Comment: you can't have optional parameters before required parameters, it wouldn't make sense (routing is based on the segments)

Comment: will you be able to add conditions here? like `customParams` param will pass or not?

Comment: If yes, then I have solution for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Make 2 routes for it, because in your case, the parameter is optional.

In web.php:

```
Route::get('{customParams?}/{slug}/{registrationCode}/detail', 'HomeController@details');
Route::get('{slug}/{registrationCode}/detail', 'HomeController@detail'); // add new route with different function name
```

In controller:

```
/* your default function will call when your customParams have some value */
public function details($customParams = null, $slug, $registrationCode) {
    dd($customParams, $slug, $registrationCode);
}

/* when your customParams will empty which is your 2nd case */
public function detail($slug, $registrationCode) {
    $this->details(null, $slug, $registrationCode);
}
```

So as a result:

When URL calls with this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/welcome/slug/r-code/detail`:

[image: case 1]

When URL calls with `http://127.0.0.1:8000/slug/r-code/detail`:

[image: case 2]